# PHP Store variables in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to save the variable score in the $chartdata[0] array.  If I put in a regular value let's say "20", i have no problem.  However, when I try to reference the $score variable the values do not get stored in the array.  It works fine if I use the random function and even when I echo out score I can see my values coming out fine.  What am I doing wrong?

```
while ($i < 5) {
  $date=mysql_result($result,$i,"date");
  $score=mysql_result($result,$i,"rating_score");
  echo $score;
  $chartData[0][] = $score;
  $chartData[1][] = rand(250,4000);
  $chartData[2][] = rand(250,4000);
  $categories[$i] = 'Label-' . $i;
  $i++;
}
```

The page is here: http://www.thelocalgolfer.com/chart/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: *"It doesn't work"* [doesn't explain the problem](http://stuck.include-once.org/#help3) enough. You need to elaborate on your input, expected and actual outcomes, or concretise error messages. In your question you become quite unspecific on what the output should be for example. Also it's not clear what you've been trying to debug this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I fully see the sense of your code (as you simply overwrite `$chartData` all the time so what's left when loop is done is last entry score and rands), but answering your question: instead of

```
$chartData[0][] = $score;
$chartData[1][] = rand(250,4000);
$chartData[2][] = rand(250,4000);
```

do this

```
$chartData[0][] = $score;
$chartData[0][] = rand(250,4000);
$chartData[0][] = rand(250,4000);
```

When you are lost with arrays using `print_r()` or `var_dump()` on them usually helps to see what is really inside (i prefer `print_r()` if I do not care content, due to formatting)

Comment: Also to avoid overwriting your array with each iteration of the loop you could use the loop control variable as your index:

    $chartData[$i][] = $score;
    $chartData[$i][] = rand(250,4000);
    $chartData[$i][] = rand(250,4000);

Comment: Well, I'd rather set temporary array and then add it at once to `$chartData[] = $tmpArray;` to avoid introducting additional variable.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of clarity.  I am trying to plot points on two different lines.  $chartData[0] is the first line $chartData[1] is the second line - if you click back here http://www.thelocalgolfer.com/chart/ you will see the graph will come up because a hard coded the values:`while ($i < 5) {
   $date=mysql_result($result,$i,"date");
   $score=mysql_result($result,$i,"rating_score");
   echo $score . ', ';

  $chartData[0][] = 21;
  $chartData[1][] = 22;
  //$chartData[2][] = rand(250,4000);
  $categories[$i] = 'Label-' . $i;
    $i++;
}`  I have the problem when using my variable $score